# How to interpret confidence intervals from R t.test when log transforming the data

Tags: r, t-test, lognormal-distribution

I have a quite large dataset that contains the time it took to make two different types of requests over a network. I would like to calculate how big the difference between the two types are. I was planning to use t.test function in R to do that.

The data is skewed with heavy right tail (for both groups), so I take the log of the values, which seems to make it quite normally distributed. If anyone is interested in the dataset you can find it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxzmgRR6TC-2Sm1MbFk4SHZpcTQ/view?usp=sharing (To get it more human readable I divide the values with 1000, before taking the log, to make the unit into seconds instead of milliseconds)

Now when I run t.test I get this output:

```
t.test(logged_sec ~ group, paired = F, var.equal = F, data = joined)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  logged_sec by group
t = -189.39, df = 125940, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.180047 -1.155873
sample estimates:
mean in group a mean in group b 
       1.321956        2.489916
```

How do I interpret this:

```
 95 percent confidence interval:
     -1.180047 -1.155873
```

?

If I exponentiate -1.18 I'll get a very small number (in this context), so I think that I should do -exp(1.18), but is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the confidence limits for the difference (groupA - groupB) in the log scale. Equivalently, confidence limits for $\log(groupA/groupB)$, the log of the *ratio* of times between the two groups. Changing the sign before exponentiation just gives the CI for $\log(groupB/groupA)$.

If you want data in terms of seconds or milliseconds or whatever you have to back-transform the coefficients into that scale. But the analyses were done in the log scale so the CI won't be correct in the back-transformed time scale.

Simplest will be to exponentiate the CI and report them as the equivalent of the CI for the ratio of the task times.